# ¿Por qué lo llamamos "piropo"?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos, acepciones

Descubro, no sin cierta sorpresa, que la segunda acepción de "**piropo**" es:

> [**piropo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TAxKpSP)
>   Del lat. *pyrōpus* 'aleación de cobre y oro de color rojo brillante', y este del gr. πυρωπός *pyrōpós*.
>
> 2. m. Variedad de granate de color rojo intenso.

Y, aunque jamás he visto usarlo así, lo cierto es que tiene sentido, atendiendo a su etimología.

Lo que no entiendo entonces es: ¿cómo llegó "piropo" a ser el nombre que le damos a ese halago que se le dice a alguien, normalmente por su belleza?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Efectivamente, proviene del griego y significa *pyrós*, fuego y *ops* (de *opós*) cara. Por lo tanto viene a sugerir rojez en la cara, sonrojarse, que es lo que sucede cuando a alguien le dicen cosas agradables, por ejemplo de su belleza, como apuntas. También puede provenir de de *pyr*, fuego y *ops*, que es mirada, y viene a decir mirar con fuego, con pasión.

Indagando algo más, he encontrado que efecivamente, significa rubí, que era una de las piedras que se regalaban durante el cortejo, y el que no podía permitírselas, utilizaba las palabras, por lo que eran un equivalente.

Comment: @walen Efecticamente, es rubí en griego. He añadido algo más de información referente a ello. Gracias.

Comment: https://www.granadadigital.es/ocho-piropos-para-conquistar-con-elegancia/

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piropo_(mineral)

Answer (score 3):

Cito al diccionario etimológico abreviado de Corominas, en su entrada sobre el prefijo *piro-*:

> *Piropo* 'cierta piedra preciosa', h. 1440; 'requiebro', 1843, y quizá ya princ. S. XVII: trasladó su sentido por emplearse con frecuencia en tratados y poesías retóricas como símbolo de lo brillante, y luego se empleó como comparación lisojera para una mujer bonita: del lat. *pyrōpus* 'aleación de cobre y oro, de color rojo brillante', y éste del gr. *pyrōpós*, adj., 'semejante al fuego', 'de color encendido' (formado con *Ops* 'aspecto').

Efectivamente, en la edición de 1843 del DLE se encuentra la primera acepción equivalente al actual *piropo*, como sinónimo de "lisonja" o "requiebro" (*requebrar* significa "halagar a alguien, especialmente a una mujer, con piropos o palabras que destaquen sus atractivos", y de hecho *requiebro* es la palabra que se usaba antes de aparecer *piropo*).

La evolución que comenta Corominas se puede constantar en textos del CORDE. En primer lugar en su acepción como piedra:

> *E cuentase Germania enbiar uno semejable al cristal mas resplandesçiente con color amarillo, e el Yspano, morante en la region Lusitana, enbia otro detramante llamas e semeiable en color al piropo.*
>
> Anónimo, "Lapidario. Título de las declaraciones de las naturalezas de las piedras", c 1420 (España).

De ahí se pasó a usar la palabra para describir a mujeres hermosas, igual que se usaban otras piedras preciosas para el mismo efecto.

> *CURA. ¿Qué les parece? Doña Dura es bella.
>
>   CORNELIO. Digo que es un piropo, es una estrella,
>
>   pero, dómine cura,
>
>   yo no quisiera la mujer de dura.*
>
> Francisco Bernardo de Quirós, "Aventuras de don Fruela", 1656 (España).

De ahí pasó al significado actual:

> *A este Caballero le nombra y califica, entre otros, con los epítetos y piropos siguientes.*
>
> Bartolomé José Gallardo, "Apología de los palos dados", 1811 (España).

Yo entiendo que este último paso fue debido al hecho de que los piropos solían hacer sonrojar al piropeado, haciendo que la persona pasara a asemejarse a un *piropo*. Se pueden encontrar en la hemeroteca algunos textos de finales del siglo XVIII que también usan *piropo* como "requiebro", pero no he podido remontarme mucho más atrás, todos los casos anteriores parecen ser de *piropo* como "piedra" (en su uso literal o figurado).